# How can I deal with AFJSONRequestOperation 's response when my service return text/html?

Tags: afnetworking

I'm new to AFNetWorkingk and my question is when I use AFJSONRequestOperation,my service returned a text/html result! Any one can give me some suggestions?Or other methord to implement this？

Comment: There's nowhere near enough info here for us to even make a guess as to what is wrong. Basically: Your client code could be wrong, it could be using the wrong url or your service could be broken. Try using charlesproxy to capture a working request to the service, then capture a non-working request sent by your code, and add them both into the question along with your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `text/html` to the acceptableContentTypes like this:

```
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
```

This is definitely a better option than the one below as you don't need to alter `AFJSONRequestOperation.m`

Answer (score 2):

Go to `AFJSONRequestOperation.m`

Add `text/html`

```
+ (NSSet *)defaultAcceptableContentTypes {
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but try setting the `Accept` header to `application/json` for the `NSURLRequest`, or if that doesn't work, add a `.json` to the end of the URL.